# Norm and trace of an element in a cyclotomic number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, normed-spaces, extension-field, field-trace

Let $K$ be a number field of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\alpha \in K$. There are $n$ distinct embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$ -- and we will denote these by $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, ... , \sigma_n$. The **norm** of $\alpha$ is given by $N(\alpha) = N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha) = \Pi_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i(\alpha) \in \mathbb{Q}$, and the **trace** of $\alpha$ is given by $Tr(\alpha) = Tr_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i(\alpha) \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I am interested in the special case, $K = \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive $5$-th root of unity. Since $[K : \mathbb{Q}] = \phi(5) = 4$, there are exactly $4$ embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$. I believe that these must be given by $\sigma_1 : \omega \longmapsto \omega$, $\sigma_2 : \omega \longmapsto \omega^2$, $\sigma_3 : \omega \longmapsto \omega^3$, and $\sigma_4 : \omega \longmapsto \omega^4$.

Let $\alpha = a + b\omega + c\omega^2 + d\omega^3 + e\omega^4 \in K$. Then,

$Tr(\alpha) = (a + b\omega + c\omega^2 + d\omega^3 + e\omega^4) + (a + b\omega^2 + c\omega^4 + d\omega + e\omega^3) + (a + b\omega^3 + c\omega + d\omega^4 + e\omega^2) + (a + b\omega^4 + c\omega^3 + d\omega^2 + e\omega^1) = 4a + (b + c + d + e)(\omega + \omega^2 + \omega^3 + \omega^4)$.

Now, we have that $1 + \omega + \omega^2 + \omega^3 + \omega^4 = 0$. Thus, we have $Tr(\alpha) = 4a - (b + c + d + e)$. Is this correct ?

Now, for the norm of $\alpha$, it tiring to multiply out $\sigma_1(\alpha) \cdot \sigma_2(\alpha) \cdot \sigma_3(\alpha) \cdot \sigma_4(\alpha)$. Is there an easier or more clever way to do this, or is it just what it is ? In general, is there some general formula for $N(\alpha)$, where $\alpha \in K$ and $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $\alpha=\sum_{i=0}^4 a_i \zeta^i$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $5$th root of unity and $\operatorname{Tr}$ for the trace $\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathbf Q(\zeta)/\mathbf Q}$. Trace is $\mathbf Q$-linear, that's why you get a nice formula. Indeed,

$$\operatorname{Tr} \sum_{i=0}^4 a_i \zeta^i=\sum_{i=0}^4 a_i \operatorname{Tr}(\zeta^i).$$
Since $5$ is prime, $\zeta^i$ remains a primitive $5$th root of unity for $i=1,\ldots,4$. The sum of all conjugates of primitive $5$th roots of unity is $-1$ as you wrote, hence this becomes

$$\color{red}{a_0} -(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4).$$

Now, the norm is not linear but *multiplicative*. A priori there is no reason why $N(\alpha)$ should take some nice form.

Comment: $Tr_{L\vert K} (1) = [L:K]$, so in this case, you do get a factor of $4$ in front of the $a_0$.